Ideas to insulate telecom box in closet
Looking to insulate this box in my closet, I have cockroaches in the house and I think they are coming from this opening, because the wires go up into the attic and I seen them crawling around up there. Also want to prevent the attic heat from getting into the house from here. What can I do to insulate this? Was thinking of a thin foam with cutouts for the metal plate screws.
https://imgur.com/a/s4k4lPw

heat rises  ....

I would think if the issue is roaches, I would want to eliminate the roaches first and foremost.  Who wants roaches in their home?

Yes, what RMDman said. Call an exterminator first. Clean up and get rid of anything they can eat. They will even eat paper so remove their food supply along with the exterminator. Then worry about insulation.
